# How do we measure the brightness of the stars?

Tags: star, observational-astronomy, brightness

How do scientists measure the brightness of so distant stars?

Comment: We can easily say their *visible limunosity*. The problem to solve: it is not easy to say, we have a star X light years away, or a star twice brighter, 2X light years away. Might read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_distance_ladder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term *brightness*, or *apparent brightness*, is used to describe how bright a star appears to us from Earth. The term *luminosity* is used to describe how bright the star is physically, also called *intrinsic brightness*.

As light spreads from a star to the viewer, it diverges inversely proportional to the square of its distance (d) from the viewer.  $\begin{equation}B \propto \frac{1}{d^2}
\end{equation}$.

The relationship between brightness (B) and luminosity (L) is described by $\begin{equation}B = \frac{L}{4\pi d^2}
\end{equation}$ (1). So we have three variables, **brightness**, **luminosity** and **distance**.

So out of those three, you'd need two to acquire the third. The distance is generally the hardest to acquire. The gold standard in measuring the distance to a star is [stellar parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_parallax). If you can't do parallax, then distance-independent properties of stars sometimes serve as clues to distance.

Measuring brightness is generally the easy one. [CCD's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device) are often used to measure apparent brightnesses. Brightness can be expressed in [stellar magnitudes](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/glossary/stellar_magnitude.html) or absolute fluxes.

So to sum up, we calculate or measure distance, we measure apparent brightness and finally calculate the luminosity value from (1).