# Distance and absolute brightness

Tags: distances, absolute-magnitude, nova

This is an exercise from a text, I’m learning from and I can’t understand it so I’m asking just to develop my knowledge:

> The explosion of V603 Aql (Nova Aquilae) took place in June 1918. The nova reached maximum brightness -1.1 mag. The nova's spectrum was observed to shift absorption lines corresponding to a radial speed of 1700 km/s. In 1926, a weak envelope was observed around the nova with an angle of 16''.
>
> Determine the distance and absolute brightness at maximum for V603 Aql.

Comment: Sounds like an exam question.

Comment: It’s from the book, I’m learning from and I can’t understand it so I’m asking just to develop my knowledge

Comment: I've made a small adjustment to the format based on your comment. Can you double check the book for the end of the first quoted paragraph, is it 16 arcseconds (16") or 16 arcminutes (16')? Thanks!

Comment: "the book?" what book?  What don't you understand about it?

Comment: Perhaps add the reference of the book you are citing ?

Comment: A good starting point for tackling this is looking into approximating the distance using stellar parallax. I've answered a question on this Exchange on determining the brightness of stellar objects. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36025/how-do-we-measure-the-brightness-of-the-stars/36026#36026